# Code star framework add metabox to a specific page

Tags: wordpress, themes, meta-boxes

I am using the code star framework full version. I have integrated the framework with the theme. **How can I show the meta box option only for some specific pages** ( like home page and about page )? Currently, the meta box options are showing all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating metabox, you should pass "page_templates" value in array. For example, if you want to show metabox on homepage you should do:

```
    $homePage = 'home-page';
    CSF::createMetabox($homePage, array(
      'title'          => 'Homepage',
      'post_type'      => 'page',
      'page_templates' => 'index.php', //filename goes here
      'data_type'      => 'serialize',
    ));
```

For more info: http://codestarframework.com/documentation/#/configurations?id=metabox-option-framework